# What is wrong with the colorbox examples?

Tags: colorbox

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem I need help with.

- download the latest version of `colorbox` (version 1.3.19) from [the site](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)
- unzip it
- open index.html under example folder 1, 3, 4 or 5.
- click on the link `Outside HTML (Ajax)`

At this point I get the error `this content failed to load`

Looking at the raw html it all looks good. How can I fix this example to make it work so I can do ajax loading of an html page using colorbox?

PS if you look under the example2 folder, it doesn't work either. I didn't include it above only because it doesn't show the error message.

My setup: Firefox 13.0.1 on Ubuntu 10.04LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local use of ajax is disallowed by most browsers (see: Access-Control-Allow-Origin).  Put it on a server and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one!

Answer (score 0):

It only works with Internet Explorer on my machine. But it does not with Firefox nor Chrome. You just opened Pandora's box, my friend...

Comment: ok sounds like I need to file a bug on it. thanks for the help!

Comment: in case other's are interested in tracking: here is the link to the bug: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/234